# Correct way to update class attributes in python?

Tags: python, class

I saw in another question that you can get and set class attributes like so:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        self._name = val
```

I'm just wondering why we do this when it looks like I can also just do:

```
x = SomeClass(name='Ari')
x.name = 'StackOverflow'
```

Can someone explain to me the purpose of the `@property` and `@<attribute>.setter`

Comment: You would typically have this in `__init__()`: `self._name = name`

Comment: Please refer the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: Those `property`s are *totally pointless*. Don't do it that way. The whole *point* of property is to *avoid* boilerplate getters and setters.

Comment: @MarkMeyer well, in this case, you would just do `self.name = name`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am assuming (maybe incorrectly) that this example was simplified to make a minimal, complete example. Clearly, if you are doing nothing in getter or setter other than getting and setting there's no point. On the other hand, this is almost *exactly* the example in the documentation, which presumably is not there to be *totally pointless*.